# I can't insert foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have a node db with five pieces of data:

- id(int, PK)
- question(varchar)
- result(varchar)
- left_id(int, FK)
- right_id(int, FK)

and two foreign keys in the same table

- left_id -> id
- right_id -> id

here is my bean

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
@NotNull
private int id;

@Column (name = "question")
private String question;

@Column ( name = "result")
private String result;

@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="left_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=true, updatable=true)
private Nodes left;

@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="right_id", referencedColumnName="id", table="node", insertable=true, updatable=true)
private Nodes right;
```

and here is my dao

```
public void insert_question(String question, int left) throws HibernateException
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Nodes node = new Nodes();
            Nodes leftNode = new Nodes();

                    //insert question
            node.setQuestion(question); 

                    // insert left_id with fk   
            leftNode.setId_node(left);
            node.setLeftNodes(leftNode);

            session.saveOrUpdate(node);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have a same insert method for result but without foreign key.

My new question and new result are insert my db but not my left_id.

In Eclipse, hibernate tell me

```
Infos: Hibernate: select nodes_.id, nodes_.question as question0_, nodes_.result as result0_ from node nodes_ where nodes_.id=?
Infos: Hibernate: insert into node (question, result, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Infos: Hibernate: insert into node (question, result, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

When hibernate insert a new data, why there are no left/right_id ?

thanks

EDIT:

I changed my hbm. Before it was like that

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.beans.Nodes" table="node">
        <id name="id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="question" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="question" />
        </property>
        <property name="result" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="result" />
        </property>


        <one-to-one name="left" class="com.beans.Nodes" access="field"></one-to-one>
        <one-to-one name="right" class="com.beans.Nodes" access="field"></one-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and now it's like that

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.beans.Nodes" table="node">

        <id name="id" type="int" access="field">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

        <property name="question" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="question" not-null="false"/>
        </property>
        <property name="result" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="result" not-null="false"/>
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="Left" 
            column="left_id" 
            unique="true"
            not-null="false"
        />

        <many-to-one name="Right" 
            column="right_id" 
            unique="true"
            not-null="false"
        />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and it's works !

Comment: Can you share all code from the `Nodes` bean? Is there a node in the database with the id passed as `left` parameter?

Comment: Hi, I changed my hbm changing the mapping and it's works !. i'll make an edit for a solution ;). thanks a lot